# bigquery timeouts at limit. Need help making query more efficient

Tags: google-bigquery

My query below is taking more than 6 hours to run.  BigQuery quits at 6 hours.  in the first table there's 1.2Bn Records, and 135Mil Records in the second.
I don't know how to make the query run faster than six hours.   Any Recommendations would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    Source, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    MiddleName, 
    Gender, 
    Age, 
    DOB, 
    Address, 
    Address2,
    City, 
    State, 
    Zip, 
    Zip4, 
    TimeZone, 
    Income, 
    HomeValue, 
    Networth, 
    MaritalStatus, 
    cast(IsRenter as string) as IsRenter, 
    HasChildren, 
    CreditRating, 
    Investor, 
    LinesOfCredit, 
    InvestorRealEstate, 
    Traveler, 
    Pets, 
    MailResponder, 
    Charitable, 
    PolicalDonations, 
    PoliticalParty, 
    coalesce(P.ATTOM_ID, T.ATTOM_ID) as ATTOM_ID,
    coalesce(P.GEOID, T.GEOID) as GEOID,
    Score,
    Score1,
    Score2,
    Score3,
    Score4,
    Score5,
    PropertyLatitude AS Latitude,
    PropertyLongitude AS Longitude
FROM `mDB.DS.Stage_P_1` P  
INNER JOIN `mDB.DS2.TBL2` T ON P.Zip = T. PropertyAddressZIP
            AND ( 
                    LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.DeedOwner1NameLast)
                    OR LOWER(P.LastName) = LOWER(T.PartyOwner1NameLast)
                )
            AND ( 
                    STRPOS(LOWER(P.Address), LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull) ) > 0
                    OR STRPOS(LOWER(T.PropertyAddressFull), LOWER(P.Address) ) > 0 
                )
            AND IFNULL(T.PropertyAddressFull,'') != ''
```

Comment: You have a fairly complex join condition between the two tables.  On top of this, the join condition is using string operations.  In most other databases, you could change your table design such the join happened on actual columns, and then use indexing.  But, since BigQuery does not support indices, I don't know what else can be done here.

Comment: Clustering by the (lowercased) `LastName` and `Address` columns might help, if that's an option. Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables